# Using an object as a storage for variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, object, coding-style

In some cases I like it to group my variables by context by prefixing the variable name, like (example 1)

```
var context_var1 = "value";
var context_var2 = "value";
var context_var3 = "value";
var context_var4 = "value";
```

Right now I'm about to write a script and I had a look at different declaration styles, like e.g. "only-one-var-keyword-style" (example 2)

```
var context_var1 = "value",
    context_var2 = "value",
    context_var3 = "value",
    context_var4 = "value";
```

or "comma-first-style" (example 3)

```
var context_var1 = "value"
    , context_var2 = "value"
    , context_var3 = "value"
    , context_var4 = "value"
    ;
```

. But to be honest, I really like the first example most. ***Personally*** I consider it to be the most readable style.
However I thought about the following:

```
var context = {
    var1 : "value",
    var2 : "value",
    var3 : "value
};
```

Then I could access the values by

```
console.log(context.var1);
```

So what do you think. Is it a good idea to use a JavaScript object as some kind of variable storage?

EDIT:
Since it was requested a couple of times, below is a real world example where I store some vars into an object.

```
        /**
         *
         * Dom nodes which will be used a couple of times on various places.
         * Grouped into an object by context.
         *
         * @type {DOM nodes}
         *
         */
        var $dom = {
            document : $( document ),
            head : $( "head" ),
            body : $( "body" )
        };


        /**
         *
         * Calculate values based on the document height and
         * window width.
         *
         * @return {Object}
         *
         */
        var gauge = function() {

            var body_fontsize = parseInt($dom.body
                .css( "font-size" )
                .replace( "px", "" ), 10
            );

            var window_width = window.screen.availWidth;
            var document_height = $dom.document.height();
            var bline_count = Math.round( document_height / body_fontsize );
            var vline_count = Math.round( window_width / body_fontsize );

            return {
                width : window_width,
                height : document_height,
                baselines : bline_count,
                vertlines : vline_count
            };

        };
```

Comment: What do you think the JS objects are for if not for storing some data?

Comment: @zerkms Well yes of course. But the common way for declaring simple variables seems "always" to be like examples 1-3.

Comment: @Ube Maybe in procedural programming. Not in javascript.

Comment: It depends on ... eh ... context. Of the three first I like the first, like you. Grouping the vars in an object makes sense some times. It, for example, makes it easier to pass them around as arguments. Other times they are not used as a unit. And when you're  already inside for example a function, you're alreay in a common context. So it really depends on what they are used for, and what makes conceptually sense. My conclusion about the fourth option, keep in your tool box and use it when it makes sense.

Comment: +1 for the above. Show us your actual code, not a made-up example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, that's what objects are there for and they will provide the possibility to namespace your data.

However, there may be a downside to using objects: If your code is performance-critical, you should rely on local variables – although a smart choice would be generally saving (groups of!) data in objects and then just assign them to local variables within the critical code.

The reason for this is that property lookups take longer than looking up local variables. This means that

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
    doSomething(myObj.subObject.anotherObject[i]);
}
```

will execute faster if you avoid the constant lookup chain:

```
var actuallyNeeded = myObj.subObject.anotherObject;
for (var i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
    doSomething(actuallyNeeded[i]);
}
```

As long as your code isn't critical in terms of performance, this is unnecessary, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is **namespace**. And, in JavaScript, Objects works awesome for it.

Definitely it is the most used namespace declaration syntax.

Comment: It's not namespacing when local variables are grouped together into an object/unit. Usually you're already in a local variable scope when variables are defined like this, and then namespacing makes no real sense.

Comment: I beg to disagree. Even though, the local variables remark is correct. I can't see its relevance for the question

Comment: Most of the time you're declaring a group of variables, it's within a local scope where there is no risk of variable name conflict. So there is no need for different namespaces. Only when adding functions and vars to the global scope is there a need for namespaces. But even then a closure, creating a local unnamed scope, is just as useful. I agree that this syntax is good for creating namespaces, but I think that has no relevance for the question. Maybe we just understand the question differently?

Comment: What's the obsession with narrowing it to *only* local variables? I never mentioned such a thing anyways